# Change css using python and flask

Tags: python, css, flask

I want the output inside my variable msg4, which is linked to my html file, to have green color if an else statement occurs. I can't do it in render_template because if the else statement does not occur, the font color of the message will be red, as I wrote on my css file. It would be great if I could change my css file just when this else statement is called, because this msg4 would be the final output then.
Here is the else statement with the message I want to give green color:

```
        else:
            # If the form data is valid, now update user table
            cursor.execute("UPDATE user SET FirstName = %s, LastName = %s, Email = %s WHERE UID = %s", (firstName, lastName, email, id))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            msg4 = 'Changes successfully saved!'
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the css, you can change the color in html. You can use jinja2 templates to pass the color value from python to html.

Html

```
style='color: {{msg4color}}'
```

Then in python set the color value to red or green depending on the else statement. Then pass it on to the render template